# C++ Console - New lat/lon coordinate using azimuth and range

Tags: c++, geospatial, haversine

I would like assistance understanding this code I found during a search. I have been stuck for 2 weeks trying to get it and it's holding my project back. I am honestly trying to learn as I go and not just be a script kiddie about it, but this is much more complicated than the rest of my project even though I am trying. (I just learned about **auto** today while trying to understand this code, for example.)

I am working on a weather app and I know the lat/lon of the radar site. I need the lat/lon of a feature the radar has detected based off of the azimuth/range that the radar tells me (example, 271 degrees and 7 nautical miles). I need to understand how I can use this code below to convert the azimuth/range to a new lat lon coordinate. I don't require the other functions, just to be able to put my variables (starting coords, azimuth and range) and get a result. The code below looks to do much more than that, and it is confusing me.

I see the following code near the end :

```
auto coordinate = CoordinateToCoordinate(latitude1, longitude1, angle, meters);
```

... Which looks to be the part I would need out of this. I see how it's calculating it but once I dig deeper I just get myself confused. I have tried hacking at the code so much that I gave up and don't even have any examples.

I would like to be able to set my variables manually (example cin>>) and have the lat and lon output into a variable that I can save to a text file. I am able to do everything myself (ingesting the starting variables and writing the result to a text file) except the actual conversion itself.

How could I get started with this using the code below?

My example variables are :

```
Original Latitude = 29.4214

Original Longitude = -98.0142

Azimuth from Origin = 271 degrees 

Range from Origin =   6 nautical miles (I can convert to meters if needed, 
in this case it's 11112 meters)
```

The actual unedited code is below and  [a copy at this link.](https://ideone.com/9yuONO) If I get help with this I won't just copy/paste and I will come back with the completed code after I make it. I really am wanting to understand as I go, so I can be better with these advanced topics and not be constrained in the future. Code below :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>


// Source: // http://w...content-available-to-author-only...o.uk/scripts/latlong.html

static const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846, earthDiameterMeters = 6371.0 * 2 * 1000;

double degreeToRadian (const double degree) { return (degree * PI / 180); };
double radianToDegree (const double radian) { return (radian * 180 / PI); };

double CoordinatesToAngle (double latitude1,
                           const double longitude1,
                           double latitude2,
                           const double longitude2)
{
  const auto longitudeDifference = degreeToRadian(longitude2 - longitude1);
  latitude1 = degreeToRadian(latitude1);
  latitude2 = degreeToRadian(latitude2);

  using namespace std;
  const auto x = (cos(latitude1) * sin(latitude2)) -
                 (sin(latitude1) * cos(latitude2) * cos(longitudeDifference));
  const auto y = sin(longitudeDifference) * cos(latitude2);

  const auto degree = radianToDegree(atan2(y, x));
  return (degree >= 0)? degree : (degree + 360);
}

double CoordinatesToMeters (double latitude1,
                            double longitude1,
                            double latitude2,
                            double longitude2)
{
  latitude1 = degreeToRadian(latitude1);
  longitude1 = degreeToRadian(longitude1);
  latitude2 = degreeToRadian(latitude2);
  longitude2 = degreeToRadian(longitude2);

  using namespace std;
  auto x = sin((latitude2 - latitude1) / 2), y = sin((longitude2 - longitude1) / 2);
#if 1
  return earthDiameterMeters * asin(sqrt((x * x) + (cos(latitude1) * cos(latitude2) * y * y)));
#else
  auto value = (x * x) + (cos(latitude1) * cos(latitude2) * y * y);
  return earthDiameterMeters * atan2(sqrt(value), sqrt(1 - value));
#endif
}

std::pair<double,double> CoordinateToCoordinate (double latitude,
                                                 double longitude,
                                                 double angle,
                                                 double meters)
{
  latitude = degreeToRadian(latitude);
  longitude = degreeToRadian(longitude);
  angle = degreeToRadian(angle);
  meters *= 2 / earthDiameterMeters;

  using namespace std;
  pair<double,double> coordinate;

  coordinate.first = asin((sin(latitude) * cos(meters))
                        + (cos(latitude) * sin(meters) * cos(angle)));
  coordinate.second = longitude + atan2((sin(angle) * sin(meters) * cos(latitude)),
                                        cos(meters) - (sin(latitude) * sin(coordinate.first)));

  coordinate.first = radianToDegree(coordinate.first);
  coordinate.second = radianToDegree(coordinate.second);

  return coordinate;
}

int main ()
{
  using namespace std;
  const auto latitude1 = 12.968460, longitude1 = 77.641308,
             latitude2 = 12.967862, longitude2 = 77.653130;

  cout << std::setprecision(10);
  cout << "(" << latitude1 << "," << longitude1 << ") --- "
          "(" << latitude2 << "," << longitude2 << ")\n";

  auto angle = CoordinatesToAngle(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2);
  cout << "Angle =  " << angle << endl;

  auto meters = CoordinatesToMeters(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2);
  cout << "Meters = " << meters << endl;

  auto coordinate = CoordinateToCoordinate(latitude1, longitude1, angle, meters);
  cout << "Destination = (" << coordinate.first << "," << coordinate.second << ")\n";
}
```

Comment: So are you actually asking how to input `latitude` and `longitude` parameters from the console using `std::cin` but have these variables defined using `auto`?

Comment: Even that question is a little rough for me. I would like to input the latitude and longitude parameters using std::cin but have them processed using the math within the code, and returned in a variable I can display or write to a file myself.  I hope that explains it well enough.

Comment: And what hinders you to do so? What did you try? How that didn't work? Sorry I don't understand what's your real question yet. Nothing should hinder you to do something like `auto longitude = 0.0; std::cin >> longitude;`

Comment: I think you are understanding what I mean now - but it is possible I am not understanding the code enough to fully explain. I may be beyond the edge of what I can understand and what I can't. I do see how longitude would be simple to input - but look at 'angle' for example - it is defined as ' CoordinatesToAngle(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2)' and I can't just do 'angle = 271' or something simple - because it must be converted to radians first. I think this is where I don't understand how to make it work.

Comment: You first take the angle as input in degrees. In the next step you call the function to convert it to radians (ideally using a separate variable for the result), then you can use it for the calculations.

Comment: I tried using - 'angle = degreeToRadian(271);' to test with - but I then get a compiler error : line 85 [Error] invalid operands of types "const char [7] and "const char [2]"  to binary "operator/" .... I think the issue here really is me missing a more fundamental understanding of C++ (since the math is already written in the code). Every time I fix one thing, there is another error and so forth. I thank you for your time trying to help me with this but I may not be able to do this. It is most likely more simple than I think.

Comment: Don't try to put such additional information in comments. Rather [edit] your question to provide a [MCVE] that exactly reproduces the problem you're stuck with. All of that prose and irrelevant code isn't useful to help you with what your real problem boils down to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

std::pair<double,double> CoordinateToCoordinate (double latitude,
                                             double longitude,
                                             double angle,
                                             double meters)
{
...
...
}

using namespace std;

int main() {

   double lat, lon, angle, dist;

   cout << "Enter lat:";   cin >> lat;
   cout << "Enter lon:";   cin >> lon;
   cout << "Enter angle:"; cin >> angle;
   cout << "Enter dist:";  cin >> dist;

   auto coordinate = CoordinateToCoordinate(lat, lon, angle, dist);
   cout << "Destination = (" << coordinate.first << "," << coordinate.second << ")\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Thank you - I had made this more complicated than it was. That was the problem!

Comment: You’re welcome. Good luck with your project and come back if you get stuck again.